# Creating a bootstrap modal in asp mvc with ajax makes screen dark, but does not display modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a parent view which creates a javascript array, when a button is pressed, the list is passed to the controller, cast as a viewmodel, and the partial view is returned.

Everything here works. I can verify the html code is returned.

```
$(function () {
    $("#AddProduct").click(function () {
        var data = JSON.stringify(list);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetReceipt", "POS")',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: data,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (items) {
                //this part doesn't work
                $('#modal-container').modal();
                $('#modal-content').html(items);
            }
        });
    });
```

This is the modal div:

```
<div id="modal-container" class="modal fade"
     tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

The point is, the html markup is returned at `success`. But the modal is not shown, only the screen gets dimmed. I suppose the problem is somewhere here: `$('#modal-content').html(items);`... or maybe not.

Comment: The issue is on the selector you are using. From `$('#modal-content').html(items);` you need to change it to `$('.modal-content').html(items);`.

Comment: oh wow, this is embarrasing. Please make an answer, I'll mark it as correct